# Properties of exponentation - inductive

Tags: group-theory, induction

Is it possible to prove that $x^a x^{-b} = x^{a-b}$ Using only these axioms?
 $$ a^n \cdot a = a^{n+1} $$
 $$ a^0 = e $$ Where e is the identity element of the operation
 $$a^{-n} = (a^{-1})^n$$

Comment: why  $x^a x^b = x^{a-b}$ it should be  $x^a x^b = x^{a+b}$

Comment: And $a^n \cdot a^n = a^{n+n}$, not $a^{n+1}$...

Comment: @user8795  Sorry, that was a typo - I have already fixed it.

Comment: I thought maybe $\cdot$ was not the usual multiplication for this group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $x^{-c}=x^{-c}$. Applying the rule $a^n\cdot a=a^{n+1}$ once would get: $x^{-c}\cdot x=x^{1-c}$. Let $d=a$, and instead apply the rule $d$ times to get $x^{-b}\cdot x \cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x = x^{d-b}$ (where the ellipsis means $d$ applications of the rule). Since $x \cdot x\cdot \ldots\cdot x = x^d$ then $x^{-c}\cdot x^d=x^{d-c}$. Now let $a=-c$ and $-b=d$ to get $x^{a}\cdot x^{-b}=x^{-b+a}$. Since the addition of exponents is just ordinary addition $-b+a=a-b$ and $x^{a}\cdot x^{-b}=x^{a-b}$